# ¿Como modificar el valor de un elemento de un array en mongodb?

Tags: array, mongodb

El caso es que tengo el siguiente documento y quiero modificar la duración de la canción Sleepwalker, pero antes de llegar a ella hay un array. 
He probado a modificar campos que aunque son anidados no contienen arrays y me ha funcionado, pero con este código no me deja modificarlo, imagino que por el array.

Mi consulta es:

```
db.discos.update({"album.Pistas.titulo":"Sleepwalker"},{$set {"album.Pistas.minutos":"5:55"}})
```

Pero me da el error:

```
"errmsg" : "cannot use the part (Pistas of album.Pistas.minutos) to traverse the element ({Pistas: [ { numero: 1, titulo: \"Sleepwalker\", minutos: \"5:54\" }, { numero: 2, titulo: \"Washington is Next\", minutos: \"5:19\" }, { numero: 8, titulo: \"A tout le monde\", minutos: \"4:11\" } ]})"
```

¿De que manera puedo modificarlo?

```
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("59453dd6408e5a3ff4e80ad6"), 
    "album" : {
        "genero" : "Trash Metal", 
        "titulo" : "United Abominations", 
        "anyo" : NumberLong(2007), 
        "interprete" : "Megadeth", 
        "componentes" : [
            {
                "nombre" : "Shawn Drover", 
                "instrumento" : "Batería"
            }, 
            {
                "nombre" : "James LoMenzo", 
                "instrumento" : "Bajo"
            }, 
            {
                "nombre" : "Dave Mustaine", 
                "instrumento" : "Guitarra y voz"
            }, 
            {
                "nombre" : "Glenn Drover", 
                "instrumento" : "Guitarra"
            }
        ], 
        "Pistas" : [
            {
                "numero" : NumberLong(1), 
                "titulo" : "Sleepwalker", 
                "minutos" : "5:54"
            }, 
            {
                "numero" : NumberLong(2), 
                "titulo" : "Washington is Next", 
                "minutos" : "5:19"
            }, 
            {
                "numero" : NumberLong(8), 
                "titulo" : "A tout le monde", 
                "minutos" : "4:11"
            }
        ]
    }
}
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("594540bf7169d0b20671b6be"), 
    "album" : {
        "genero" : "Rock raruno", 
        "titulo" : "Origin of Symmetry", 
        "anyo" : NumberLong(2001), 
        "interprete" : "Muse", 
        "componentes" : [
            {
                "nombre" : "Dominic Howard", 
                "instrumento" : "Batería"
            }, 
            {
                "nombre" : "Christopher Wolstenholme", 
                "instrumento" : "Bajo"
            }, 
            {
                "nombre" : "Matthew Bellamy", 
                "instrumento" : "Guitarra y voz"
            }
        ], 
        "Pistas" : [
            {
                "numero" : NumberLong(1), 
                "titulo" : "Bliss", 
                "minutos" : "4:59"
            }, 
            {
                "numero" : NumberLong(2), 
                "titulo" : "Space Dementia", 
                "minutos" : "5:15"
            }, 
            {
                "numero" : NumberLong(3), 
                "titulo" : "Citizen Erased", 
                "minutos" : "7:32"
            }
        ]
    }
}
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("594540df7169d0b20671b6bf"), 
    "album" : {
        "genero" : "Rock Alternativo", 
        "titulo" : "Origin of Symmetry", 
        "anyo" : NumberLong(2001), 
        "interprete" : "Muse", 
        "componentes" : [
            {
                "nombre" : "Dominic Howard", 
                "instrumento" : "Batería"
            }, 
            {
                "nombre" : "Christopher Wolstenholme", 
                "instrumento" : "Bajo"
            }, 
            {
                "nombre" : "Matthew Bellamy", 
                "instrumento" : "Guitarra y voz"
            }
        ], 
        "Pistas" : [
            {
                "numero" : NumberLong(1), 
                "titulo" : "Bliss", 
                "minutos" : "4:59"
            }, 
            {
                "numero" : NumberLong(2), 
                "titulo" : "Space Dementia", 
                "minutos" : "5:15"
            }, 
            {
                "numero" : NumberLong(3), 
                "titulo" : "Citizen Erased", 
                "minutos" : "7:32"
            }
        ]
    }
}
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("594540fd7169d0b20671b6c0"), 
    "album" : {
        "genero" : "Hard Rock", 
        "titulo" : "Cosmic Egg", 
        "anyo" : NumberLong(2009), 
        "interprete" : "Wolfmother", 
        "componentes" : [
            {
                "nombre" : "Dave Atkins", 
                "instrumento" : "Batería"
            }, 
            {
                "nombre" : "Lan Peres", 
                "instrumento" : "Bajo"
            }, 
            {
                "nombre" : "Andrew Stockdale", 
                "instrumento" : "Guitarra y voz"
            }
        ], 
        "Pistas" : [
            {
                "numero" : NumberLong(1), 
                "titulo" : "California Queen", 
                "minutos" : "3:55"
            }, 
            {
                "numero" : NumberLong(2), 
                "titulo" : "New Moon Rising", 
                "minutos" : "3:46"
            }, 
            {
                "numero" : NumberLong(3), 
                "titulo" : "White Feather", 
                "minutos" : "3:04"
            }
        ]
    }
}
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5945410b7169d0b20671b6c1"), 
    "album" : {
        "genero" : "Blues Rock", 
        "titulo" : "Icky Thump", 
        "anyo" : NumberLong(2007), 
        "interprete" : "The White Stripes", 
        "componentes" : [
            {
                "nombre" : "Meg White", 
                "instrumento" : "Batería"
            }, 
            {
                "nombre" : "Jack White", 
                "instrumento" : "Guitarra y voz"
            }
        ], 
        "Pistas" : [
            {
                "numero" : NumberLong(1), 
                "titulo" : "You Don’t Know What Love Is", 
                "minutos" : "3:54"
            }, 
            {
                "numero" : NumberLong(2), 
                "titulo" : "Conquest", 
                "minutos" : "2:48"
            }, 
            {
                "numero" : NumberLong(3), 
                "titulo" : "Catch Hell Blues", 
                "minutos" : "4:18"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Tenes que usar el "operador $ posicional"

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/

en tu caso creo que es :

```
db.discos.update(
              {"album.Pistas.titulo": "Sleepwalker"},
              {$set : {"album.Pistas.$.minutos" : "5:55"}})
```